# Formatting a variable in iReport according to specified pattern

Tags: variables, format, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to build a report with iReport. I have defined the a variable named: **totalCosts**. This variable is based on this expression:

```
$V{costs}.multiply(new java.math.BigDecimal($F{numberOfItems}.intValue()))
```

I want to format this variable by the following pattern:

```
#,##0
```

**What I tried before asking this question:**

I tried to use the following variable expression but no success:

```
new java.math.BigDecimal(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0").format($V{costs}.multiply(new java.math.BigDecimal($F{numberOfItems}.intValue()))))
```

My variable is a **java.math.BigDecimal**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display the variable in a report, then normally you should just have a Text Field with a value of "$V{MyVariable}" (without the quotes). Set the pattern for that Text Field as you like. It saves you all of the trouble of formatting things yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using this field in a chart. That is the same, right? I define a field **$V{MyVariable}** and us this in the chart?

Comment: Yes, the same ideas apply. You don't want to chart a String; you want to chart a number (a BigDecimal). Then you need to set the label appropriately.